# Сreating buffer in meters using GeoPandas

Tags: python, buffer, geopandas, polygon-creation, measurements

I want to use a built-in function buffer of GeoPandas. I want to create a buffer of 10 centimeters around the original geometry but buffer method take argument in degree, so what value do I need to pass to achieve 10 centimeter buffer for projection of EPSG:4326?

`.buffer()` takes arguments in degree format only, how can I use meters format? Do I need to change the projection?

```
df['geometry'].buffer(meter_value)
```

Comment: I will reproject to a Projected Coordinate System in meters. Also check this: https://gist.github.com/joaofig/4a68db62ba1b9a7049d2eb50571ec9bd

Comment: If you reproject to `epsg=5070`, the unit is meters

Answer (score 6):

Yes you need to reproject into a coordinate system with meters as units.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r'C:\GIS\data\tempdata\points_wgs84.shp')
df = df.to_crs(3043) #Pick another
df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].buffer(0.1)
df = df.to_crs(4326) #Back to 4326
```